# webpack with ocLazyload fails to load both controller and template files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, oclazyload, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

```
var templatePath = require('../templatePath');
var controllerPath = require('../ControllerPath');

$scope.loadNgModules = function(templatePath, controllerPath) {
    var files = [];
    if (templatePath) files.push({ type: 'html', path: templatePath });
    if (controllerPath) files.push({ type: 'js', path: controllerPath});
    if (files.length) return $ocLazyLoad.load(files)
};
```

`ocLazyLoad` is not working When I use webpack for minification. Since I guess ocLazyLoad accepts only **path of the template and controller** but webpack is bundling both template and controller into the single minified file so it fails to load.

**Webpack plugin name :** `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'`

**Is there any way to accomplish this problem using ocLazyLoad.?**  **Can I load a string of template and controller file other than considering path.?**

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding basically ocLazyLoad accepts only path of the script and template files

So I have resolved this issue by using `$templateCache`

```
if (angular.isString(templatePath) && templatePath.length > 0) {
angular.forEach(angular.element(templatePath), function (node) {
    if (node.nodeName === "SCRIPT" && node.type === "text/ng-template") {
        $templateCache.put(node.id, node.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

}

Hope this will helps to someone :-)